# Given an array of integers return positives, whose equivalent negatives present in it

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have implemented solution in javascript using two loops, below is the code

```
function getNums(arr){
 var res = [];
 var found = {};
 var i, j;
 var arrLen = arr.length;

 for(i=0; i<arrLen; i++){
   if(!found.hasOwnProperty(arr[i])){
    for(j=0; j<arrLen; j++){
      if(arr[i]+arr[j] === 0){
        var num = arr[i];
        if(num > 0){
            res.push(num);
          found[num] = 1;
        }
      }
    }
   }
 }
 return res;
}

console.log(getNums[-1, -2, 0, -4, 1, 4, 6]); // Output: [1, 4]
```

Whose time complexity is O(n2). Can someone suggest better solution / refined above to have less complexity?

Comment: please add the data `arr` and the wanted result `res` as well.

Comment: What is the purpose of the code? Looks like you are trying to find all pairs of numbers that sum to 0, but you still need to mention it. You can't expect people to read your code and guess your motto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add the array to a Set and filter for inclusion in the set. Determining if something is in a set is constant time:

```js
let arr = [-1, 2, 3, 1 , 3, -3, 4, -6]
let s = new Set(arr)

// all positive numbers with corresponding negatives in the set
let filtered = arr.filter(item => item > 0 && s.has(-1 * item))
console.log(filtered)
```

An alternative is to sort the array and then walk two pointers up the array as making matches along the way. The result will be sorted, however, which may not be the same order as the original array:

```js
let arr = [-2, -3, 2, 5, 3, 1, -6, 2, -5]
arr.sort()

// get startig indexes
let i = 0, j = arr.findIndex(n => n > 0)
let res = []
if (j > -1) { // only if there are positive numbers in the array
    while(arr[i] < 0 && j < arr.length){
        if (-1 * arr[i] === arr[j]){
            res.push(arr[j++])
        } else if(-1 * arr[i] > arr[j]){
            j++
        } else if(-1 * arr[i] < arr[j]){
            i++
        }
    }
}
console.log(res)
```

Comment: please try with `[1, 2, -3, -4, 2, 3, 4, 4, -4, 4]`. `Set` does not know the count.

Comment: @NinaScholz, I get `[ 3, 4, 4, 4 ]` as a result. That's the result I expect — all positive numbers where there's an existing negative in the array. Maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: as i read the question, it should have pairs of negative and positive values.

Comment: @NinaScholz, yes I could see that too. It could be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a *single* loop approach by counting the values.

```js
function getNums(array) {
    var count = Object.create(null),
        result = [];

    array.forEach(v => {
        if (count[-v]) {
            result.push(Math.abs(v));
            count[-v]--;
            return;
        }
        count[v] = (count[v] || 0) + 1;
    });
    return result;
}

console.log(getNums([1, 2, -3, -4, 2, 3, 4, 4, -4]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use filter and includes prototype functions which are well optimized.

```
const getNums = (arr) => arr.filter((num, index) => num > 0 && !arr.includes(num, index + 1) && arr.includes(-num));
```

Comment: Featuring an array with integers from -200 to 6000, the execution is about two times faster.

Answer (score 0):

Before the downvotes... This answer is not the shortest javascript code, but the algorithm - I think it is what the original question was about.

One way to get rid of nested loops is to use more memory to store intermediate structures. In your case, you want to store not just the "found" flag, but negative, positive values as well, so that at every iteration you can set the found flag. Then you also use the "found" flag to prevent adding the results 2nd time.

```
var f = function(arr) {
  let hash = {};
  let res = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      // put value into the hash map  for future use
      hash[arr[i]] = arr[i];
      var absVal = Math.abs(arr[i]);

      // if value is not 0 AND if it has not been found yet (x+value hash) AND if both negative and positive values are present
      if( arr[i] !== 0 && !hash["x"+absVal] && (hash[arr[i]] + hash[-arr[i]] === 0)){

          // then set the found hash to  true
          hash["x"+absVal] = true;

          // and push to the resut
          res.push(absVal);
      }
  }

  // return the result
  return res;
}
```